# Select subcategories based on Main Categories in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a little problem with Joomla admin content. I couldn't find module or how to edit Joomla content categories while creating new article.

**Now the categories showing like that:**
[image]

*What I want to do*: **if admin choose the category like "News", after that he need to choose subcategory:**
[image]

Comment: It is better to ask all Joomla question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.